# Cannot install geopy 0.96.1 with buildout

Tags: python, plone, zope, buildout

A lot of builds in our CI failed this morning.
Example: https://jenkins.4teamwork.ch/job/ftw.contentpage-master-test-plone-4.3.x.cfg/427/console

```
...
No eggs found in...geopy-0.96.1...(setup script problem?)
...

Error: Couldn't install: geopy 0.96.1
```

I can reproduced this also on my machine with the same buildout.

I downloaded and installed geopy 0.96.1 with a "clean" virtualenv manually:

```
virtualenv-python2.7 setup.py build -> works
virtualenv-python2.7 setup.py install -> works too
```

I could use an older version of geopy, but I guess there's something wrong with this version of geopy. And I also want to test against the most recent version.

I also removed the cached geopy source (tar.gz) on the server and downloaded the file manually, but also no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I look at the History of geopy it seems to be broken because of a wrong MANIFEST.IN which was fixed in master(https://github.com/geopy/geopy/commit/57133938328dc55eeca896ebfbe883cebf860a47). There is also a new tag on github already but not yet on pypi.

I took the package from Source and checked out the 0.96.2 tag. This worked fine for me.

Comment: @mr-hide Thanks, I'm waiting for the new release -.-